# Best XML standard for importing page information

Tags: java, xml, standards

I am planning to create a **new specification** for an XML generated from our WCMS system.

This XML will be used to **import pages** (with *child pages*) in our portal.

It will also have **locale specific** page information.

Can anybody suggest a good XML standard which is best suitable for this.

**Note:** I was trying out ATOM but it doesn't seem to support hierarchy of entry elements.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score -1):

If you create a new specification (i.e. XML schema) than you can use XSD to create it. It is the most common and best supported schema definition language.